# How to collect all the objects in the object into a single array

Tags: javascript

When I click the button, I want to include all the objects in the itemSold and itemGet objects of the customers into the products array. how can I do that?

```js
let customers = [{
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    product: {
      itemSold: [{id:1,name : 'car'}, {id:2,name : 'home'}],
      itemGet: [{id:3,name : 'phone'}, {id:4,name : 'fly'}],
    },
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 2,
    product: {
      itemSold: [{id:5,name : 'lamb'}, {id:6,name : 'mouse'}],
      itemGet: [{id:7,name : 'mouse pad'}, {id:8,name : 'tv'}],
    },
  },
];


  
let clickButton = document.querySelector("#clickButton");
let products = [];


clickButton.addEventListener("click", getProcuts()});

function getProducts(){}
```

```html
<button id="clickButton" >Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 let customers = [{
      active: true,
      id: 1,
      product: {
        itemSold: [{ id: 1, name: 'car' }, { id: 2, name: 'home' }],
        itemGet: [{ id: 3, name: 'phone' }, { id: 4, name: 'fly' }],
      },
    },
    {
      active: true,
      id: 2,
      product: {
        itemSold: [{ id: 5, name: 'lamb' }, { id: 6, name: 'mouse' }],
        itemGet: [{ id: 7, name: 'mouse pad' }, { id: 8, name: 'tv' }],
      },
    },
    ];



    let clickButton = document.querySelector("#clickButton");
    let products = [];

    clickButton.addEventListener("click", getProducts);

    function getProducts() {
      for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        products.push(...customers[i].product.itemGet, ...customers[i].product.itemSold);
      }
      console.log(products);
    }
```

```html
<button id="clickButton">Click</button>
```

We loop our customers array and then select product property there we push both itemSold and itemGet arrays into products.

Answer (score 1):

You can map over the customers and concatenate the arrays.

```js
const customers = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    product: {
      itemSold: [
        { id: 1, name: "car" },
        { id: 2, name: "home" },
      ],
      itemGet: [
        { id: 3, name: "phone" },
        { id: 4, name: "fly" },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 2,
    product: {
      itemSold: [
        { id: 5, name: "lamb" },
        { id: 6, name: "mouse" },
      ],
      itemGet: [
        { id: 7, name: "mouse pad" },
        { id: 8, name: "tv" },
      ],
    },
  },
];

const products = customers.map((customer) => {
  return customer.product.itemSold.concat(customer.product.itemGet);
});

console.log(products);
```